# TextBlock doesn't show Text even after Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I wanted to add a list of text to ListBox as soon as the user press the Button..Each ListItem contains `TextBlock` to which am binding the data..

But the `TextBlock` is **not** showing the text! Though I could see the Background color of each Item being inserted!

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="CLICK" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    <ListBox x:Name="dataList" Foreground="Red" Background="Blue">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Feed}" FontSize="28"></TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

My code behind looks like

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    ObservableCollection<Data> data;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        dataList.ItemsSource = data;
    }
    class Data :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Data(String s)
        {
            Feed = s;
        }
        private string _feed;
        public String Feed
        {
            get { return _feed; }
            set { _feed = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Feed"); }
        }
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        data.Add(new Data("News1"));
        data.Add(new Data("News2"));
        data.Add(new Data("News2"));
    }

}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `Data` needs to be public else it would have `private` access specifier by default..

So it should be

```
public class Data.....
```

Everything else seems to be ok..